# Kubernetes and Docker Support

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Kubernetes is stopping the support of Docker. What exactly does this mean for my Docker containers in my Kubernetes cluster?

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.20.md#deprecation

Answer (score 6):

No need to worry. Kubernetes will not be using the docker engine to manage containers. For more info take a look at this thread:
https://twitter.com/Dixie3Flatline/status/1334188913724850177

If you are a user, just ignore it. If you are an operator, change to CRI-O or `containerd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was probably a bit too fast and I just read it. Here is the official statement again.

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/